# How to make Windows java-based app handle deep linking?

Tags: java, windows, deep-linking

The JDK has support for Desktop.setOpenURIHandler but it seems that this only works for MacOS. 
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#setOpenURIHandler-java.awt.desktop.OpenURIHandler . Windows support deep linking, but it does not seem to work with Desktop.setOpenURIHandler https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/web-to-app-linking